# Delete / Un-assign Group numbers to units in Supreme Commander 2

Tags: supreme-commander-2

While I love the fact that I can assign more than one group # (using CTRL + *number *to a particular unit or combination of units), I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to un-assign, or delete that group designation, from a unit.  And it drives me crazy.

Also, on the flip side, if anyone knows what secret combination of actions will let me change the group designation number without adding an additional group designation, that would be pretty cool as well.  Say if I wanted to change my WASPS from group 1 to group 3.

I couldn't find anything in the settings on how to do this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the group designation for a unit, assign the units to the new group, deselect all units, then press Ctrl + the old group number (this assigns the group to nothing).

The only way to remove units from a group is to select the group, deselect the specific units, then re-assign those units to the same group.

Comment: This is standard for pretty much every RTS game.

Comment: @StrixVaria: actually, Starcraft has the annoying problem of not really benig able to empty your selection, so it's basically impossible to do the first items.